# How to submit only a item from a Html.DropDownList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have in a view, something like:

```
@model List<General.StuffDto>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Stuff", FormMethod.Get)) {
    @Html.DropDownList("StuffSelect", new SelectList(Model, "Id", "Name"))
}
```

And I want to make a Get request like this:

> localhost:1234/Stuff/123456

Where 123456 is the value from selected item from the DropDownList.

How to make this Get Request? Preferentially without using javascript.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do this without javascript.

Comment: Why not do the GET request to localhost:1234/Stuff and in the Controller action check for the selected item?

Comment: You need JavaScript on the client side to parse out the values and send the request.

Comment: Check the name attributes given to the drop down list in your generated HTML. If the name matches a  parameter in the controller action, it should be picked up by the action. Other than that, its just a case of adding a form submit, and the correct parameters.

If you think the GET is not hitting the right URL, use fiddler to check it out.